# How do I link Newlib memcpy into bare-metal project?

Tags: c, bare-metal, newlib

I'm trying to compile a simple project for a TM4C123GXL microcontroller using arm-none-eabi-gcc. Inside `main` I call `memcpy` just to test that it works as expected, but it causes a fault. What causes the fault is inside the disassembly of `memcpy` one of the first instructions is `b.n 0xc7a`, which takes the CPU to some unused segment of flash. It's as though `memcpy` expects some other function to be at that location, but I can't figure out why that would happen when any dependencies should get linked as well. And in fact, they do. A look at the symbols in the ELF show that other functions are also included. It compiles without any warnings or errors.

Here is the Makefile I'm using:

```
PROJECT = main
SRCS = $(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ = obj/
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJ), $(notdir $(SRCS:.c=.o)))
INC = inc/
LD_SCRIPT = TM4C123GH6PM.ld

CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld 
OBJCOPY = arm-none-eabi-objcopy
RM = rm -rf
MKDIR = @mkdir -p $(@D)

# EDIT: include -O0 flag
OPT += -O0

CFLAGS = -ggdb3 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=softfp -MD -std=c99 -c -Wextra -Wall -Wno-missing-braces
CFLAGS += $(OPT)


all: bin/$(PROJECT).elf


$(OBJ)%.o: src/%.c          
    $(MKDIR)              
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -I$(INC) $(CFLAGS)
    
bin/$(PROJECT).elf: $(OBJS) 
    $(MKDIR)           
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -Wl,-T $(LD_SCRIPT) -Wl,-e Reset_Handler
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $@ bin/$(PROJECT).bin 

clean:
    -$(RM) obj
    -$(RM) bin
```

And my `main`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    uint8_t x[] = {1,2,3};
    uint8_t y[] = {0,0,0};

    uint8_t *xptr = x;
    uint8_t *yptr = y;
    memcpy(yptr, xptr, 3);

    while (1)
        ;
}
```

And my `Reset_Handler`, for good measure:

```
void Reset_Handler(void)
{

    int *src, *dest;

    /* copying of the .data values into RAM */

    src = &_etext;
    for (dest = &_data; dest < &_edata;)
    {
    *dest++ = *src++;
    }

    /* initializing .bss values to zero*/

    for (dest = &__bss_start__; dest < &__bss_end__;)
    {
    *dest++ = 0;
    }

    main();
}
```

Is there something else I need to do in order to use Newlib's standard C library?

Comment: Try disabling the compiler optimization, use -O0 flag. I know that this is enabled by default but it may be possible that for embedded targets the toolchain may be using some default optimization under the hood.
I can also see that you are using `-mthumb`. Any specific reason? Please try removing that flag and check once.

Comment: @GauravPathak I added that but still no luck.

Comment: Please try adding a fault handler, I am not sure exactly what's happening. If the code is crashing (ARM is generating a fault), please add a fault handler and examine the CPU Registers and also add some details e.g. add the disassembly. Try some debugging at your end, the more information you can provide the better it is for anyone else to help you with this issue.

Comment: Try to specify `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16  -mfloat-abi=softfp` flags when linking.

Answer (score 0):

[KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk)'s comment helped me to solve the problem, specifically, including `-mthumb` when linking.

I think the reason this is required is because when no options are specified to arm-none-eabi-gcc (as is the case when the Makefile calls it in the second step to do linking) it uses `-marm` by default:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'bin/main.elf' '-v' '-mcpu=arm7tdmi' '-mfloat-abi=soft'
'-marm' '-mlibarch=armv4t' '-march=armv4t' '-dumpdir' 'bin/main.elf.'
```

The TM4C uses a Cortex-M4F CPU which only supports Thumb instructions. My own files were compiled as Thumb instructions since I included `-mthumb` in their compilation before linking, but without this option specified when I linked the files, the ARM version of `memcpy` was included. The CPU interprets the ARM instruction as a Thumb instruction, and that leads to all sorts of bugs.

Moreover, as [Guarav Pathak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805824/gaurav-pathak) pointed out, it is not necessary to manually include `-mthumb` when `-mcpu=cortex-m4` is specified, as this flag automatically includes `-mthumb` with it. As long as `-mthumb` is included some way or another, that will direct the compiler to link the Thumb versions of other compilation units.

Comment: Uuuuhm, sure, it may work _for memcpy_ to do just `-mthumb` -  but other standard functions may use or profit from other instructions sets. You want to specify the same options to the compiler and to the linker. See `arm-none-eabi-gcc --print-multi-lib` for how many versions there are.

Comment: @KamilCuk Newlib has libc implementations entirely in Thumb; that's the only option for Cortex-M processors.